# Cufon.refresh() don`t work in IE8

Tags: javascript, fonts, cufon

I need to refresh Cufon fonts after getting AJAX data. Unfortunately simple Cufon.refresh() don`t work in IE8. Debugger says, tah the line 1191

```
sStyle.width = roundedShapeWidth;
```

has Invalid argument.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. Not only in Cufon.Refresh but also when Cufon.Now occured. And not only in IE8, but in IE7, IE6 and even in IE9PP. I noticed that I use this code for replecament:

```
Cufon.replace('h1',{hover: true})('h2',{hover: true})('h3',{hover: true})('cite',{hover: true})('.cufon',{hover: true});
```

The ('.cufon',{hover: true}); part was the one which generated the error. I spent two days to find out, how it could raise an error...

I opened CSS, looked for .cufon sytling. There was no .cufon in CSS. And cufon didn't inherit styles in IE series, insted an error occured.

So I added this to my CSS:

```
.cufon { }
```

and error went away.

(Using Cufon 1.09)

Comment: Umut, when Cufon runs, it adds elements with the class 'cufon'. It's best to avoid this class entirely as it will probably cause other problems than the one you had. Have a look in a DOM inspector - it's quite interesting to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I just reused Cufon.replace instead:

```
Cufon.replace('h1',{fontFamily: 'StackOverflow'});
```

Only inconvenient I see is that if you want to refresh all contents, you need to re-list them all:

```
Cufon.replace('h1, h2',{fontFamily: 'StackOverflow'});
Cufon.replace('h3', { fontFamily: 'StackOverflow Light'});
```

Comment: +1 I had a similar problem; refresh() didn't work for me, I could only replace() again.